# Maven run works in command line not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, command

Created Maven project from Elcipse Orxygen 2. 
Using jetty server and trying to display just the index jsp on localhost link.

1. Compiled from command prompt + run from command prompt -> works.
2. Compiled from Eclipse + run from command prompt -> works
3. Compiled from Eclipse + run from Eclipse -> doesn't work.

Console and Maven console does not display any warning and also does not display Info messages (this problems is for all other projects too).

Comment: Anything of relevance in the error log? Repeat the failing scenario, then **Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration tab -> View Error Log** and look for anything strange with a timestamp around the time of the failure.

Comment: Error log -> "!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.refactoring' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.menu' is invalid): org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor.RenamePomAction".

Comment: Error log -> "!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.refactoring' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.menu' is invalid): org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor.RenamePomAction".  I am not sure if this is causing the problem.   1) Java applications run without any issue.  2) In Maven console, I see the command mvn -B <path to maven settings.xml> jetty:run.  If I copy and paste it to command line, it works fine.

Comment: There are several old Eclipse bugs for that error message. Can you update your post with the following: [1] A larger portion of the error log. [2] Full details of your Eclipse version. [3] Go to **Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations** and post the details of the checked version of Maven in the **Installations** pane.

Comment: 1) Full error log info -> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2018-03-16 12:35:33.795
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.refactoring' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.menu' is invalid): org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor.RenamePomAction
2) Eclipse info - Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600  3) Only Maven software is checked - apache-maven-3.5.2.  Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I don't think it will help but one easy thing to try is to select your project node in Project Explorer, right click and select **Maven -> Update Project** from the popup menu.

Comment: I have tried it before and tried it again. Does not fix the issue.  Other simple java projects are running fine from Eclipse. Only Maven has problem.  I reinstalled M2E, Eclipse, Maven.  Does not seem to fix the problem. I don't know if refactoring issue is a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have all the m2e software.  Installed me2 wtp and the issue has been resolved.